# THREE JS draw line as a child of object pointing to Vector non related with object or parents

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have scene with objects as a parent /child.

I need to define a `Vector3` relative to (deepest) `child` object which pointing on vector in scene (`look_point`).

```
var grandParent = new THREE.Object3D();
var parent = new THREE.Object3D();
var child= new THREE.Object3D();

var look_point = new THREE.Vector3();

grandParent.position.set(9,5,3);
grandParent.rotation.set(1,2,3);

parent.position.set(5,8,3);
parent.rotation.set(2,1,3);

child.position.set(2,5,3);
child.rotation.set(3,2,1);

scene.add(grandParent);
grandParent.add(parent);
parent.add(child);



var m = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFF00FF, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,  transparent: true, opacity: 1, depthTest: false })

/// draw line in scene
var v = new THREE.Vector3().copy(child.position);
    v = parent.localToWorld(v);
    v = grandParent.localToWorld(v);

var g = new THREE.Geometry();

    g.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3().copy(v)); 
    g.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3().copy(look_point));   


scene.add(new THREE.Line(g,m));    

// how to get relative points to draw line with child object as a parent

var g2 = new THREE.Geometry();

    g2.vertices.push(???); //// how to get Vector3 relative to child pos and rot?
    g2.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3());   

child.add(new THREE.Line(g2,m));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `look_point` is in world frame then you'll want to transform the points into the local coordinate frame of the child.

You can use the `Object3D.worldToLocal` function to achieve this. Here's a rough idea of how:

```
// ensure the world matrices are all up to date
scene.updateMatrixWorld(true);

g2.vertices.push(child.worldToLocal(new THREE.Vector3().copy(v)));
g2.vertices.push(child.worldToLocal(new THREE.Vector3().copy(look_point)));   
child.add(new THREE.Line(g2,m));
```

It's important to ensure that all the world matrices have been calculated ahead of time. Let me know if that works out for you!

Comment: thx, what exactly obj.worldToLocal does? it goes through all the nested objects between obj and scene and use their matrices to calculate final point position? I mena on what object i have to call the function, on parent THREE object of a calculated point?

Comment: `obj.worldToLocal` does the opposite of `obj.localToWorld`, so it transforms a point from being relative world frame to being relative to the obj frame (including scale, rotation, position). You can read up more in the docs and source code (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.worldToLocal) but basically the function takes the inverse of the objects worldMatrix (which transforms points into world frame when multiplied) and multiplies the point by it.